# Perl split on any delimitter

Tags: perl, split

How do i split a line with a variable as a delimiter. Variable can be anything example
`:` `,` `\s` `|` `.` or any word.

Tried this:

```
GetOptions (
    'f1=s' => \$file1,
    "fs1=s" => \$fs1
);

open(fh1, $file1);

while(my $row1 = <fh1>) {
    chomp $row1;
    @temp=split(/\Q$fs1/, $row1);
}
```

but this does not work. I am taking `$fs1` (file seperator) as input from user.

Comment: If your delimiter is `\s` or `|`, you will need to escape the command-line arguments in the shell. How are you running your program? Print out `$fs1` to make sure it is getting to the perl executable correctly.

Comment: It's always wise to explain what you mean by *"does not work"*. On its own that is of no help at all

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine as long as you don't specify any regex metacharacters

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

my $fs1 = ':=';

my $row1 = 'a:=b:=c:=d:=e';

my @fields = split /\Q$fs1/, $row1;

use Data::Dump;
dd \@fields;
```

#### output

```
["a" .. "e"]
```

The only problem I can think of is that, if you specify something like `\s` then the `\Q` will escape it so that you will be splitting on the two characters backslash followed by `s` instead of a whitespace character. Perhaps you just need to remove the `\Q`? But then you would have to escape characters like square brackets, braces, pipes etc. on the input line

Answer (score -2):

`\Q` is the beginning of quoting, you should have `\E` to end the quoting:

```
@temp = split(/\Q$fs1\E/, $row1);
```

To see what's happening there, you could try `quotemeta`. It does exactly the same as `\Q ... \E`:

```
print quotemeta($fs1);
```

This will work if `$fs1` is anything like letters, numbers or RegEx special chars, maybe a `+` or `*`.

If you want to pass RegEx specials, remove the `\Q`:

```
@temp = split(/$fs1/, $row1);
```

Now `$fs1` may contain, for example, `\s` to split at any space-like char or `a+` to split at any number of `a` letters.

Comment: You *don't* need `\E` to end the escaping. It simply continues until the end of the pattern if unspecified